# ggplot2: add hline only to one grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

Assume the following data:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
X <- data.frame(
    x     = 1:10,
    y     = sample(1:20, 10), 
    group = sample(paste0("g", 1:3), 10, replace = TRUE), 
    type  = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 5),
    style = rep(c(0, 1), each = 5)
)

> X
    x  y group type style
1   1  6    g1    a     0
2   2  8    g1    a     0
3   3 11    g3    a     0
4   4 16    g2    a     0
5   5  4    g3    a     0
6   6 14    g2    b     1
7   7 15    g3    b     1
8   8  9    g3    b     1
9   9 19    g2    b     1
10 10  1    g3    b     1
```

And the plot below:

```
ggplot(X, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point(aes(color = group)) +
    facet_grid(. ~ type)
```

Which looks like this:

[image: plot]

The goal is to add a `geom_hline` with `yintercept = 10`, but only to the left grid (everything else should remain the same). I tried the script below:

```
ggplot(X, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point(aes(color = group)) +
    geom_hline(aes(linetype = style), yintercept = 10) + # does not work
    # geom_hline(data = X[X$type == "b", ], yintercept = 10) + # doesn't work neither
    facet_grid(. ~ type)
```

But it adds an horizontal line to both grids. Any workaround?

**Solution**:

```
geom_hline(data = data.frame(yint = 10, type = "b"), aes(yintercept = yint)) +
```